# Finding a counterexample: If $f=g^2$ and $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$, then $g$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$.

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Suppose $f,g:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$.

Provide a counterexample: If $f=g^2$ and $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$, then $g$ is differentiable on $(a,b)$.

I've been attempting to find a counterexample by picking a $g$ and then squaring it to get $f$. Whatever I try and let $g$ be, I can't find one that isn't also differentiable on the same interval. Any suggestions as to what type of functions I should be looking at would be great.

Comment: How about $g(x) = 1$ if $x$ is rational and $-1$ if $x$ is irrational?

Comment: And if $g$ shall be continuous, look at $\lvert\,\cdot\rvert$.

Comment: Take $g(x)=|x|$, $f(x)=g(x)^2=x^2$. Then $f$ is differentiable at $0$, $g$ is not. Both are continuous there.

Comment: I suspect taking $g(x)=x\sin \frac1x$ (with $g(0)=0$) will do as well, and is more interesting. But I'm too lazy to verify this before posting, so I'll let you check it. I suspect the derivative oscillates near zero, but the squaring flattens the function sufficiently to allow it to become differentiable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** We can let simply $f:=1$ then the values of $g$ can be either $+1$ or $-1$, it neither has to be continuous.